# session starts automatically in PHP 5.6.8?

Tags: php, session

I'm running php 5.6.8. I'm trying to build a website. I've called session_status() on multiple pages and it always returns true. Why does that happen? I didn't ever call session_start(). 
I'm sorry if this question was already asked or if you can easily find the answer on google. I didn't.
Thank you.

Comment: How are you checking this? [`session_status()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php) returns an integer, not a boolean.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php ,  booleans = http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: `PHP_SESSION_NONE === 1`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say it returns 1. Isn't that the same as true?

Comment: Nope, `true` and `1` are different data types. `==` checks value, `===` checks value and type.

Comment: If you want check if the session is started, then use `PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE === session_status()` comparison

Comment: `1` is `PHP_SESSION_NONE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check should look something like this:

```
if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
```

The session_status function does not return a true or false value.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php